# i18n problem with jquery.validate.js

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, internationalization

I use a plugin jQuery validation plug-in 1.5.5.js. How to use the mechanism for i18n?

```
    messages: {
        required: "To pole jest wymagane.",
        requiredEN: "This field is required",
        remote: "Proszę poprawić to pole.",
        email: "Proszę podać poprawny adres e-mail.",
        url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
        date: "Please enter a valid date.",
        dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
        dateDE: "Bitte geben Sie ein gültiges Datum ein.",
        number: "Please enter a valid number.",
        numberDE: "Bitte geben Sie eine Nummer ein.",
        digits: "Please enter only digits",
        creditcard: "Please enter a valid credit card number.",
        equalTo: "Hasła muszą być identyczne.",
        accept: "Please enter a value with a valid extension.",
        maxlength: $.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),
        minlength: $.validator.format("Proszę wprowadzić przynajmniej {0} znaków."),
        rangelength: $.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),
        range: $.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),
        max: $.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),
        min: $.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")
```

Comment: I don't understand/see your concrete question/problem. What is the functional requirement and at what step exactly are you stucking now?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is include your respective localization file in the respective page. This will automagically translate it !

Comment: consider expanding the expanation, and adding an example.